# Uploaded image disappears in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this weird situation where an uploaded image file disappears only when using **Chrome**.

This is how it happens: I click **Choose Files** and upload an image

[image]

Then when I click **Choose Files** then I click cancel or close the window, the recently uploaded file disappears.

[image]

I tested the same page using Firefox and Safari, and it works fine,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then when I click Choose Files then I click cancel or close the
> window, the recently uploaded file disappears.

This is something that it does by default. It's all because of the Chrome browser design.

You can add the following js code to change it design, add `onclick` and `onchange` event to this upload file input control:

```
Upload Image:
<input id="imageUpload" type="file" onclick="fileClicked(event)" onchange="fileChanged(event)">


@section Scripts{
    <script>
     
        var clone = {};
        function fileClicked(event) {
            var fileElement = event.target;
            if (fileElement.value != "") {
                clone[fileElement.id] = $(fileElement).clone(); //'Saving Clone'
            } 
        } 
        function fileChanged(event) {
            var fileElement = event.target;
            if (fileElement.value == "") {
                clone[fileElement.id].insertBefore(fileElement); //'Restoring Clone'
                $(fileElement).remove(); //'Removing Original'
            } 
        }
    </script>

}
```

Here is the test in Chrome:

[image]